# C# windows form - Is it possible to programmatically determine text size through the metric system? If so, how?

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, size, units-of-measurement

You know how it's kinda awkward to format a document into the dimensions of a small card? I'm trying to write myself a program so that I can do that, partially because my handwriting is bad and I need to write some physical "thank you" cards, and partially just for the experience.

The way I was planning on doing this was by making a C# windows form and resizing a rich text box based on the measurements of the card. I would then convert it into an rtf file, so I can print it out on a computer that actually has a printer. The thing is, as far as I know, you can only resize using pixels as a metric. And pixels aren't a very consistent way to measure something that you're going to print on paper, as they're completely dependant on the resolution of your screen.

How could I resize something using a tangible measurement, like centimeters?

Comment: You could export it as a pdf maybe? There are a few pdf c# libraries, and if I remember correctly a pdf pixel has a static height/width once you specify the files dimensions, e.g letter, A4, etc...

Comment: You can determine the screen dpi and calculate from there. Also: You can set the Graphics.PageUnit.

Comment: @user3739842 I'm not entirely sure how PDF files work, tbh. I don't usually bother with them, because I prefer making documents that can be edited.

Answer (score -1):

Bitmaps measuring metric is pixels. Bitmat formats have a piece of metadata it is  DPI (dots per inch) that is used to translate a size in pixels to a size in centimeters via the simple formula:

centimeters = pixels / dpi * 2.54
when you are building your Image class you must set metadata using the SetPropertyItem Method:

PropertyTagResolutionUnit - set this to "3" for centimeter
PropertyTagXResolution - Essentially the X DPI as long as PropertyTagResolutionUnit is in centimeters 
PropertyTagYResolution - The Y DPI as long as PropertyTagResolutionUnit is in centimeters

follow this link for more information about PropertyTag Values:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee491082.aspx

http://zigmaweb.com